# How do i check if atleast one element of bitmap array is not zero?

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap

I am not looking for a function in C, a macro would be helpful. This is how I would like to use the bitmap.
Usage :

```
int bitmap;
if(bitmap != 0)
   do something
else
   do something
```

Suppose bit map becomes an array of bitmaps, how do I achieve the same result (without making a function call)?

Comment: homework tag is removed now....!!!!!

Comment: "I am not looking for a funtion in c ,A macro would be helpful"  Can you explain the reasoning behind this statement? Why can't you use a function?

Comment: the check comes in fast code path and i cant afford to have a function call overhead for each of it.

Comment: Don't worry about the cost of calling functions in C. The compiler will most likely inline that function anyway, if you set the appropriate optimization flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array:

```
int i;
int non_zero_found = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sizeofthearray; ++i)
{
    if (array[i] != 0)
    {
        non_zero_found= 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (non_zero_found)
{
    // do something
}
```